# Generating user post count and thread count from different tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema, forum

So I don't know much about MySQL but I heard about views and I'm trying to wrath my head around it.

Basically what I want to do is

1. check the table **forum_posts**, count the number of posts made by each user
2. query **forum_users** for each user to get every column and add to the view
3. query **forum_threads** to get the number of threads made by that user.

**I don't know if that order is correct performance-wise but the final view should in theory look like either**

## 1.

- UId (user id from forum_users)
- UName (user name from forum_users)
- UThreads (user thread count)
- UPosts (user post count)
- UFakePosts (named UPosts in forum_users, *I'll rename that later to UFakePosts*)
- ULastPost (this one is not that important but I'm just throwing it here in case anyone knows how to do it, I imagine it would be possible by selecting the post with the biggest *PDate* column)

## 2.

- All of forum_users but renaming the forum_users.UPosts and forum_users.UThreads to UFakePosts and UFakeThreads
- ULastPost
- UThreads (user thread count)
- UPosts (user post count)

I managed to get the post count working by using the following code

```
       SELECT
       IFNULL(a.UId,-1) AS UId,
       IFNULL(a.UName,'Unknown') AS UName,
       postsquery.Posts AS UPosts,
       IFNULL(a.UPosts,-1) AS UFakePosts
       FROM
       (
           SELECT p.PId, p.PAuthorId, COUNT(p1.PAuthorId) as Posts
           FROM forum_posts AS p
           LEFT JOIN forum_posts AS p1 ON p1.PId = p.PId
           GROUP BY p.PAuthorId
       )
       AS postsquery
       LEFT JOIN forum_users AS a ON postsquery.PAuthorId = a.UId
       ORDER BY postsquery.Posts DESC
```

which generates the following result
[image: mysql result]

but no success with getting threads, I can get one of the other but not both at the same time.

I've also tried this

```
    SELECT IFNULL(a.UId,-1) AS UId,
    IFNULL(a.UName,'Unknown') AS UName,
    postsquery.Posts AS UPosts,
    threadsquery.Threads AS UThreads,
    IFNULL(a.UPosts,-1) AS UFakePosts
    FROM
    (
        SELECT p.PId, p.PAuthorId, COUNT(p.PAuthorId) as Posts
        FROM forum_posts AS p
    )
    AS postsquery
    LEFT JOIN forum_users AS a1 ON postsquery.PAuthorId = a1.UId,
    (
        SELECT t.TId, t.TAuthorId, COUNT(t.TAuthorId) as Threads
        FROM forum_threads AS t
            GROUP BY t.TAuthorId
    )
    AS threadsquery
    LEFT JOIN forum_users AS a ON threadsquery.TAuthorId = a.UId

    ORDER BY
    postsquery.Posts DESC
```

.....but the results are wrong:

[image]

What's supposed to happen:

- Unknown (*user that I haven't scraped yet*): 1 post / 0 threads
- User1: 2 posts / 0 threads
- User2: 1 post / 2 threads
- User3: 0 posts / 0 threads

If I could do another view but for threads, getting number of unique posters and number of posts that would be cool as well but one thing at a time.

## Fiddle with database structure

### http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c93d9/1

Structure should be pretty easy to understand, **U** stands for user, **T** for thread, **P** for post, **D** for date and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subselect to get the thread count:

```
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    TAuthorId,
    COUNT(1) as thread_count
  FROM
    forum_threads
  GROUP BY
    TAuthorId
) threads ON
  threads.TAuthorId = postsquery.PAuthorId
```

And then select that column:

```
IFNULL(threads.thread_count, 0) as thread_count
```

Putting it all together:

```
SELECT IFNULL(a.UId,-1) AS UId, IFNULL(a.UName,'Unknown') AS UName, IFNULL(postsquery.Posts, 0) AS UPosts, IFNULL(threads.thread_count, 0) as thread_count, IFNULL(a.UPosts,-1) AS UFakePosts
FROM
(
    SELECT p.PId, p.PAuthorId, COUNT(p1.PAuthorId) as Posts
    FROM forum_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN forum_posts AS p1 ON p1.PId = p.PId
    GROUP BY p.PAuthorId
)
AS postsquery
LEFT JOIN forum_users AS a ON postsquery.PAuthorId = a.UId
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    TAuthorId,
    COUNT(1) as thread_count
  FROM
    forum_threads
  GROUP BY
    TAuthorId
) threads ON
  threads.TAuthorId = postsquery.PAuthorId

ORDER BY
postsquery.Posts DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I took your reply and changed it a little bit and it worked great, only problem is that when I tried to save it I got "1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause". Any tips on what I should do?

Comment: Ahh MySQL... the more I use it, the more I hate it. I wasn't even aware of this restriction with MySQL.. for me it almost defeats the purpose of views. One method is to create multiple views, 1 each for the subquery (Some 1 view for `postquery`, 1 view for `threads` and then 1 main view for the above. Hacky at best unfortunately. Do you actually need this to be created as a view? I personally don't like views.. they abstract the query away from the developer and then you aren't entirely sure what the query is doing anymore without checking the view definition.

Comment: Well that sucks, I don't know how to do it then, I've tried this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c93d9/5 but I'm not able to add threads to it as well, only posts work